# Web Server Properties Loading

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, websphere

We are in the process of migrating from Websphere servers to Tomcat servers and are having some issues getting the previous properties files to work. 
Right now the properties files are stored under `WEB-INF/properties/example.properties`
The servlets and java classes are under `src/com/java/Example.java`

The properties files under Websphere were referenced using something like this:

```
ResourceBundle props = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.example", Locale.getDefault());
```

This is NOT working under Tomcat. They are referenced from regular java classes, not from servlets, so I can't use get getServletContext() directly. The only way that I've been able to get this to work so far is by using:

```
InputStream props = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/properties/example.properties")
```

I can then pass it to the constructor of the java class from the servlet and reference it using `this.prop = prop;` The problem is, I have numerous properties files, and they all route through various java classes, making this kind of solution really quite cumbersome and inelegant, and would require more changing than I'm hoping I have to do.

I'll try to clarify anything that seems unclear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ResourceBundle` loads resources from the classpath, not from the webcontent. The file needs to go in `/WEB-INF/classes/properties/example.properties` in order to be present in the classpath and be accessed that way. That it worked in Websphere is likely just one of the many strange (non-standard) features of that server.